# Unable to inline styles with `sass-loader`

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader

I have a project setup where I use `ExtractTextPlugin` to create a CSS file. I'm trying to create a dev Webpack config with the styles injected onto the page using `style-loader`, `css-loader`, and `sass-loader`.

As far as I am aware the default behaviour is to inject the styles into a `<style />` tag and I've removed all traces of `ExtractTextPlugin` but it still doesn't want to inject the styles.

Does anybody know what might cause the styles to be lost? My Webpack config is below.

Config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = config => Object.assign({}, {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: 'bundle.js.map'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ]
}, config)
```

Called with:

```
module.exports = require('../../dev')({
  name: 'Onboarding',
  entry: './src/apps/components/Onboarding/index.js'
})
```

Comment: What is your objective? Having the CSS in side the build or as a separate file ?

Comment: Inside the bundle. I already have it working it separate files but it's too slow for development

Comment: What is slow in your development?

Comment: Build times are slow

Comment: Did you check this issue ? https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working by rewriting most of my Webpack config. I had already tried the `css-loader` options below, so I'm not sure why they worked now but not before.

This is my new dev-only config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = config => {
  const { out, libraryTarget, name = 'main' } = config
  const filename = `${name}.js`

  delete config.out

  return Object.assign({}, {
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../' + out),
      filename,
      libraryTarget,
      publicPath: '/assets/js/'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              query: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            },
            'sass-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'App Name',
        filename: '../../index.html',
        template: './test-lambda/template-dev.html',
        inject: 'body'
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: `${filename}.map`
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
      })
    ]
  }, config)
}
```